# Add PHPStorm command line for symfony framework

Tags: symfony, cmd, phpstorm

I am new with symfony framework. I use PHPStorm, and I am going to set up its commandline for Symfony. However, anytime I do the steps, I receive an error :

Failed to load commands: Failed to execute php.exe c:\xampp\htdocs..\app\console-v

. Would you please give me guidance to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Is the path really `c:\xampp\htdocs..\app\console-v`, without a backslash after `htdocs`? If so, perhaps there is a path `c:\xampp\htdocs` in some configuration file which should be made into ``c:\xampp\htdocs\``.

Comment: Thanks or your reply, but the path is correct, it is c:\xampp\htdocs\Project Name\app\console-v

Comment: If there is a space in "Project Name", that can also lead to trouble with certain software. Please do specify the exact error message in your question to avoid that kind of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly look at your current directory at command line.
secondly check to see if your path is true or not.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, but these are all ok. Also, I have downloaded the Symfony directly from its website. It is worth noting that I have version 2.4.2 of symfony.